# ZK Project Creation on Eclipse Juno using ZK studio

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, zk

I installed Eclipse Juno and added ZK Studio plugin. My Java JDK is 1.5.

However, when I tried to create a new project, I get an error like this:

> The selected wizard could not be started. Plug-in
>   org.zkoss.eclipse.zks was unable to load class
>   org.zkoss.eclipse.zks.ui.wizards.ZKProjectWizard. Bad version number
>   in .class file.

I am not able to proceed forward. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like ZK Studio needs a newer JDK that 1.5